# If 90% trader lose money can you do opposite of what they do and make money?

Tags: stocks, day-trading

Say you have a friend Bob that is bad at trading and loses money consistently.  Can you take position opposite of Bob for example if he buys a stock you secretly short it and when he sells you cover your short.  Would you turn that 90% losing money into 90% gains?

Also if this actually works then oops I guess I just gave away a free strategy.

Comment: Related: https://xkcd.com/2270/

Comment: Yes.  The opposite of what Bob is doing is investing for the long term :-)

Comment: The big challenge is in finding a trading strategy that really loses money consistently (before transaction fees).

Answer (score 8):

No -- to quote a related [answer](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/136179/64920):

> The opposite of a bad strategy is not necessarily a good strategy!

The heart of the problem is that the weighting of a portfolio affects returns *arithmetically*, while the success or failure of a strategy depends on *geometric* compounding.

Here is a simple example. Suppose Bob's strategy returns either +60% or -40% each month with equal probability. Bob is almost certain to ultimately lose his money, because on average, for every month when his wealth is multiplied by 1.6, there is a month when it's multiplied by 0.6, and 1.6x0.6 < 1.

The opposite of Bob's strategy is *even worse*, returning either -60% or +40%, leading to 0.4x1.4 < 1.

Now, here is a mind-blower:

Suppose Alice has a strategy that is exactly as bad as Bob's, but is uncorrelated. That is, Alice's strategy returns either +60% or -40% with equal probability, independent of Bob's return. Alice will lose all her money too. But suppose *you* invest half your money in Alice's strategy and half in Bob's, rebalancing monthly.

Then 25% of the time your return will be +60%, while 50% of the time it will be +10% and 25% of the time it will be -40%. So your wealth growth is determined by 1.6x1.1x1.1x0.6 > 1. The combination of Alice's strategy and Bob's strategy is profitable!

An implication is that buying only a subset of stocks in an index can be unwise, yet excluding those stocks from the index can *also* be unwise! This is the miracle of diversification: The whole is truly greater than the sum of its parts.

Comment: Unfortunately, the ‘mind-blower’ will not work out for just _any_ combination of two bad traders…

Answer (score 2):

There are a lot of reasons why day traders fail.  One that can't be overcome by taking the opposite side of the trade is transaction costs (bid/ask slippage) and commission costs if you're still paying them.  The more you trade and/or the more leverage you use, the greater the effect.

Comment: Thats why you gotta use free brockerage and only trade big cap companies problemo sovled!

Comment: And yet with free commissions, most traders still lose money.  Go figure.

Comment: Oh no I meant do the opposite of traders that use free brockerage and trade mega caps that means their trading strategy is the thing that is losing money.

Comment: @Bob Baerker:  Quite apart from bad trading decisions, a day trader faces the problem of the Gambler's Ruin.  Statistically, in a game with even odds, a gambler with finite capital will eventually go broke playing against one with infinite capital.  If they play long enough, they eventually have a run of bad luck long enough to wipe out their capital.

Comment: @bakaloo - Hypothetical example: You're playing poker at a casino and the house takes $1 per player for every hand played. After one hand, every player is down $1 except for the winner of the hand. After 100 hands, each player is down $100 to the house. It's possible there are lots of small winners in one evening (skill or luck) but if you play 5 days a week, week after week, it's more likely that only the few with serious poker skills will be in the plus column. For the market, these losses are a given and that's before the myriad of reasons (bad decisions) why traders incur losing trades.